# iOS: Prevent app from launching into the background

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, avplayer

I am currently building a music app which takes controls from the iOS7 control center. One of the features I noticed is that if I press the "play" control button, my app will start, even if it has been killed. This is not something which I want to happen, so I added `return NO` in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` if the app is launching in the background to prevent the initialization process.

Unfortunately, this does not change the fact that the app has still started, and `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` is not called again (and nothing is initialized). Since I cannot have the app forcefully kill itself when I don't want it to start, is there any way to prevent the app from launching? I had thought that returning `NO` would have done the trick, but this does not appear to be the case.

Comment: I am not sure what are you using for "play" functionality, but maybe if you unsubscribe from "play" notification when application is terminated, will do the trick?

Comment: `The return value is ignored if the app is launched as a result of a remote notification` https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

Comment: Thanks, that solves one mystery, at least.

@IvanAlek The problem with that is, there is no certain location where I could add a call such a call before the app is killed.

Comment: Throwing an exception from `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` will kill the app. Just kidding, I don't recommend doing that :)

Comment: @loadedion - your app isn't killed if it is receiving a play notification, it is just in the background. Therefore, you could unsubscribe from the notification in the `UIApplicationDelegate` using `applicationDidEnterBackground:` If you can't do it from the `UIApplicationDelegate`, then you could always have your object subscribe to the `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification` notification and remove the subscription to the play notification in that object.

Comment: If the app is still in the background, is there any reason why `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` is called? It is my understanding that this method is only called when the app is launching for the first time.

Comment: It is now expected behavior in iOS 7 that apps support resuming background audio in response to the media controls, even if they are not running. You may have your reasons, but not sure that it will pass app review if you're going for the App Store. I'm not finding anything about it in the HIG, so you may be fine, but see the [iOS 7 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-7.0/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013202-CH1-SW36)

Comment: My app does support resuming background audio. What I don't want is for the app itself to launch in the background. I have been able to reproduce this issue sporadically, which is starting to make me think that this is a bug in iOS.

Comment: Resuming bg audio from the `not running` state is [launching into the background](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW10). Check `application.applicationState` in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` for `UIApplicationStateInactive` when launched into the foreground, or `UIApplicationStateBackground` when launched into the background.  `applicationDidEnterBackground:` is then called instead of `applicationDidBecomeActive:`.

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot more sense now. Can the `running state` be controlled with any accuracy? I'm starting my app then killing it immediately. Assuming the app is in the `not running` state, I try to press the `play` through the `control center`, but it is ignored (as I originally thought it should be). The `play` is not received consistently, which is making testing a bit confusing.

Comment: I'd expect Control Center to control the last app that played media. Normal launch sends your app thru states `Not running` > `Inactive` > `Active`. Hitting the Home button then sends the app thru `Inactive` > `Background`. Killing the app then sends the app to `Not running`. Hitting the play button in Control Center would then send a notification if your app was the last app playing media in either `Active` or `Background` states. If you weren't the last playing media, then I wouldn't expect to be launched into the background when hitting play in CC, tho I haven't found exact docs on this.

Comment: Yep, I expected the same and decided to update the phone's iOS version to 7.0.4. Turns out part of my issue was an iOS bug. I was able to receive consistent background launches from the control center play button after that. Since it's consistent, I figure I can use a flag to delay the initializations until the app is actually opened and `applicationWillEnterForeground` called. In there, I can start the initialization and reset the flag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found one of the main causes to this issue. It had to do with the audio session and the various notifications/delegates which the app was registered for. In the `AppDelegate's` `applicationWillTerminate:` I had to make sure to call:

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] endReceivingRemoteControlEvents];`

`[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:NO withOptions:AVAudioSessionSetActiveOptionNotifyOthersOnDeactivation error:&audioSessionError];`

And also unregister for any audio notifications (interrupts and route changes).

Answer (score 0):

Do you want your app to run in the background at all?

If not, you can simply add a info.plist value so it doesn't enter background and just closes when a user hits the home button.

Comment: The app is made to run in the background, but not to launch to the background, although it's starting to look like it should be expected to.